# how to request data periodically from phone Sensors via a service and load it to activity (Android)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent, service

I have an idea in mind which I got a bit confused about how to implement.

I want to make for practice some "running app":
Basically a map, that gets your location when you start a running, and then draws polygones from location every X seconds (let's say x=2), calculates the distance from every polygone till the end and genreates some other details (that's not the problem).

**question 1:** How can I make the service save some data locatlly to each run? for example, I run for 60 seconds, got 30 Latlng objects and then I loop through them and then genrate the running details. Where can I save the Latlng objects, while the service is running? 
I thought about making a local DB using SQLite, then through a brodacast receiver I create an intent service that get the location and the current time, save it to local DB with the details and stop. (how can I know how much Latlngs I have on the local DB? I need to make some variable to identify it, how can I generate it each time I am calling the intent service?)
is there any other ideas you can recommend me about to do that and store the LatLng? 
when I press the "stop running" I'll just look for the latlng from the DB and then delete it.

**Question 2:**
If I am using an intent service to get the Latlng object of the current location, how can I draw a polygons at the same time on the map, in addition to the action of saving it to the local DB? ( I know Intent service cannot communicate with the UI directly. I got confused here a little bit)

I think my idea of implement and create this "mock" up is really a bad practice. If you have and ideas or places to reference me, I'll appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: You can always go ahead and query databse , how many records are there in database.
If you are asking how to query database refer
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html  .Also for communicating with UI from IntentService http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/report-status.html

Comment: is this the only possible way to save it if I create a "Running" instance? I would like to know if there is any other way to do it. I am thinking about this cause any way, I'd to delete it later any way. or possibly just upload it online if the running was completed to some BaaS Service. I mean, after I save the runnign to the local DB I want anyway to upload it to the server and delete it from the local one..@Vijay

Comment: As long as application is running, you can always keep the data in memory. But i don't think that's the case here. There are other ways to save data Sharedpreferences , in File, but as per me what you want is best done with Sqlite database. It will be easier for u to handle also.

Comment: I edited the answer again. Thank you@Vijay

Comment: You can also save data in XML files , which will be good for parsing data stored in applications / data. U can save data with xml tags with whatever structure you like (ex - Latlng and time)